Generic[T] class with access to type parameter of classmethod in Python 3.12
Similar to how one could retrieve a type from a generic class type signature via a class method, I am now interested in doing the same for the class method's type signature itself. This is for use in a creative project.
For example, I would like to print the concrete type of T in this example:
class MyClass[T]:
    kind: type[T]

    @classmethod
    def make_class[T](cls) -> "MyClass[T]":
        instance = cls()
        instance.kind = ...
        print(instance.kind)
        return instance

Currently this would result in an exception:
>>> MyClass.make_class[int]()
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

A custom "classmethod" decorator would be ideal as I imagine it would require the least amount of "hacking" to the way generic classes work.
class MyClass[T]:
    kind: type[T]

    @typed_classmethod
    def make_class[T](cls) -> "MyClass[T]":
        ...

Must I experiment with MethodType?

Please stop trying to abuse type hints for runtime stuff. That might be appropriate for a couple of validation libraries, but generally is a very bad idea. Your reference implementation, for example, will break with stringified annotation as soon as kind is used for anything but simple print. Python is not Rust or C++, type annotations here are optional and intended for consumption by tools like mypy. If you need that type at runtime, simply pass it as an argument: def make_class(cls, type_: type[T]) -> MyClass[T]: ...

You would probably be interested in PEP 718.

@STerliakov I'm asking for use in a creative project. I heed your warning but I'm still curious how one may do this using Py3.12.

Thanks @InSync I'm very interested in PEP 718!
